# Find a new cubic equation with new roots $\alpha\beta$, $\beta\gamma$ and $\gamma\alpha$. Can I use substitution for this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

Given a cubic equation $x^3+2x^2-5x+1=0$, find the equation with roots $\alpha\beta$, $\beta\gamma$ and $\gamma\alpha$.
For the case where the new roots are ${\alpha}^2$, ${\beta}^2$ and ${\gamma}^2$, I can use the substitution $y=x^2$ but for this case I can't since the new roots are products of two old roots. 
However, for the case stated in the title above, I know this can be done where we set the equation to be
$$x^3+px^2+qx+r$$
Then we can see that,
$$-p=\Sigma{\alpha\beta}=-5\Rightarrow p=5$$
$$q=\Sigma{(\alpha\beta) (\beta\gamma) }$$
$$q=\alpha\beta\gamma\Sigma\alpha=(-1)(-2)\Rightarrow q=2$$
$$-r=(\alpha\beta) (\beta\gamma) (\gamma\alpha) $$
$$-r=(\alpha\beta\gamma)^2=(-1)^2\Rightarrow r=-1$$

However, this method is quite tedious, especially if the new roots are $\alpha+\beta$, $\beta+\gamma$ and $\gamma+\alpha$. So does substitution method exist for this condition or is the one shown above the only method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=\alpha\beta=\dfrac{-1}{\gamma}$

$\implies\gamma=?$

As $\gamma$ is a root of the given equation,

replace the value of $\gamma$

For $x^2=y$

Square both sides of
$$x(x^2-5)=-(2x^2+1)$$

Replace $x^2$ with $y$

Comment: So I substitute $y=-\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @T.Joel, yes, you are correct

Comment: May I ask something similar? What about a cubic for roots ${\alpha}^2+\alpha$,  ${\beta}^2+\beta$,  ${\gamma}^2+\gamma$? It's a little difficult to find an expression for $x$ in terms of $y$ if I use $y=x^2+x$

Comment: @Joel, $4y+1=(2x+1)^2$ First find the equation of $2x+1$

Answer (score 2):

For this particular equation we have $\alpha\beta\gamma=-1$ and so
$$\alpha\beta=-\frac1\gamma\,,\ \beta\gamma=-\frac1\alpha\,,\ 
  \gamma\alpha=-\frac1\beta\ .$$
So $\alpha\beta,\beta\gamma,\gamma\alpha$ are the roots of
$$\Bigl(x+\frac1\alpha\Bigr)\Bigl(x+\frac1\beta\Bigr)\Bigl(x+\frac1\gamma\Bigr)$$
and also of
$$\eqalign{\frac{\alpha\beta\gamma}{(-x)^3}
  \Bigl(x+\frac1\alpha\Bigr)\Bigl(x+\frac1\beta\Bigr)\Bigl(x+\frac1\gamma\Bigr)
  &=\Bigl(-\frac1x-\alpha\Bigr)\Bigl(-\frac1x-\beta\Bigr)\Bigl(-\frac1x-\gamma\Bigr)\cr
  &=f\Bigl(-\frac1x\Bigr)\ ,\cr}$$
where $f(x)$ is your original cubic.